# Returning SQL data from multiple tables, limited by date range in 1 table using Athena / Presto

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I'm SLOWLY making my way through a project leveraging AWS Athena to process various log files. My goal is to use the log files for event correlation, so I need to find some way to select and display data from multiple tables, within a given time range, from a single SQL statement. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
scada.timestamp             process.eventid                         scada.srcaddr   process.requestid                       scada. action
2017-03-16T07:25:46.000Z    c148e2ce-8500-467a-a970-ef1d43dd4aea    172.31.25.225   032bfafb-e8a3-4c06-a2dc-fa740abc135     ACCEPT
2017-03-16T07:25:46.000Z    8cc8143a-cf55-4db3-b112-0ff7f268edd0    172.31.25.225   f413e138-9445-408f-8124-ee6c33229889    ACCEPT
```

---

Here is a sample of data from the 2 tables:

Table 1:

```
SELECT eventtime, requestid, eventid FROM process_native limit 10;

        eventtime               requestid                               eventid
        2016-05-07T08:57:37Z    032bfafb-e8a3-4c06-a2dc-fa740abc135c    c148e2ce-8500-467a-a970-ef1d43dd4aea
        2016-05-07T08:57:37Z    f413e138-9445-408f-8124-ee6c33229889    8cc8143a-cf55-4db3-b112-0ff7f268edd0
```

Table 2:

```
SELECT tstart, srcaddr, action FROM scada_raw limit 10;

tstart      srcaddr         action
1489509010  139.59.39.211   REJECT
1489509010  172.31.20.111   ACCEPT
```

As table 2 stores the time as unix time that complicates things a little, I need to convert that so I have a common time format to work with:

Table 2 with updated time:

```
SELECT to_iso8601(from_unixtime(tstart)) as timestamp, srcaddr, action FROM scada_raw limit 10;

timestamp                   srcaddr         action
2017-03-16T07:25:46.000Z    172.31.25.225   ACCEPT
2017-03-16T07:25:46.000Z    172.31.25.225   ACCEPT
```

---

Frankly, I have no idea how to go about this :)
Here is a query I thought up, it just times out:

```
SELECT process_native.eventid,
         process_native.requestid,
         scada_raw.srcaddr,
         scada_raw.action,
FROM process_native, scada_raw
WHERE scada_rawe.eventtime >= '2017-02-17T00:00:00Z'
        AND scada_raw.eventtime < '2017-03-20T00:00:00Z'
```

I really don't know where to go next, I've been working with SQL for all of 3 days now, and this is WAY beyond me. Is my goal even achievable?

Thank you!

Comment: The example is not clear

Comment: How are the two tables related to each other?

Comment: Sorry, the example made sense to me, but I guess that's because I wrote it :) I'm looking to correlate events, the 2 tables have nothing in common other than the event times, and even they will not be 100% identical. What I'm after may not even be achievable, but I don't know if that is the case or not. I would like to specify a time frame, then have all data that falls within that timeframe, from both tables, returned. For example if there is an error reported from the scada data, I would like to pull together all data from the scada and process logs captured during the event period.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get the records near each other, even if you can't guarantee the dates will match for a proper join.  For example:

```
eventtime               requestid      eventid        srcaddr       action
2017-03-14 16:30:10.000                               139.59.39.211 REJECT
2017-03-14 16:30:10.000                               172.31.20.111 ACCEPT
2017-03-14 16:30:11.000 032bfafb-e8... c148e2ce-85...  
2017-03-14 16:30:11.000 f413e138-94... 8cc8143a-cf...
```

From a query like this:

```
WITH TimelineRecords AS (
    SELECT 
        eventtime,
        requestid,
        eventid,
        NULL srcaddr,
        NULL action
    FROM
        process_native
    WHERE
        eventtime BETWEEN timestamp '2017-03-14 16:30:00' AND  timestamp '2017-03-14 16:35:00'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        from_unixtime(tstart) eventtime,
        NULL requestid,
        NULL eventid,
        srcaddr,
        action
    FROM
        scada_raw
    WHERE
        from_unixtime(tstart) BETWEEN timestamp '2017-03-14 16:30:00' AND  timestamp '2017-03-14 16:35:00'
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TimelineRecords
ORDER BY
    eventtime;
```

Sorry about the two WHERE clauses, Athena didn't like it when I put that on the last select statement.